# Wrapping a function imported with import *?

Tags: python, introspection

I have a set of tests which wrap some functions of a specific module suppose it looks like this: 
`alpha.py`

```
def foo(): 
    return 'foo'
def bar(): 
    return foo(), 'bar'
```

`debug_alpha.py`

```
from alpha import *
def _wrapper(func): 
    def call(*args, **kwargs):
        print('entering')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('exiting') 
        return result
    return call

def _wrapFunc(module, func): 
    module.__dict__[func.__name__] = _wrapper(func)
```

`test.py`

```
import debug_alpha
debug_alpha._wrapFunc(debug_alpha, debug_alpha.foo)
print(debug_alpha.foo())
print(debug_alpha.bar())
```

But of course the output is only:

```
entering
exiting
foo
('foo', 'bar')
```

Because while the `foo` function may have been wrapped - `bar` is still referenced to the `foo` function in the original `alpha` module. Is there a trick to wrapping `foo` in a way that `bar` will also call the appropriate `foo` without changing the import schema?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: @jedwards I wanted the wrapper to be triggered on `bar()`, I think I got it though, it's possible to `import alpha` and wrap `alpha.__dict__['foo']`, after that calling `from alpha import *`. Should I close the question if I no longer need an answer?

Comment: If you think it'll be helpful to future viewers (I don't see why it wouldn't, compared to so many questions on here), answer your own question.  You get a nifty badge for that I think.  You could also add a line to `wrapFunc` like `alpha.__dict__[func.__name__]  = _wrapper(func)` (after `import alpha`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your objective, but you could do something similar to the following:

**alpha.py**

```
# everything here is the same
def foo(): 
    return 'foo'

def bar(): 
    return foo(), 'bar'
```

**debug.py** Use the [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) to find the original module that the function was defined in.

```
# make the debug module reusable
import inspect

def _wrapper(func): 
    def call(*args, **kwargs):
        print('entering')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('exiting') 
        return result
    return call


def _wrapFunc(func): 
    # find out which module the original function was
    # declared and wrap it.
    module = inspect.getmodule(func)
    wrapped = _wrapper(func)
    setattr(module, func.__name__, wrapped)
    # return the wrapped function so that the module
    # that called this function can have access to the
    # newly created function
    return wrapped
```

**test_alpha.py**

```
# make test.py the testing script instead of depending on
# debug_alpha to handle hardcoded namespaces
import debug_alpha
from alpha import *

# wrap the function in its original module
# and override the wrapped function in this namespace
foo = debug_alpha._wrapFunc(foo)

print(foo())
print(bar())
```

**Output**

```
entering
exiting
foo
entering
exiting
('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct, since I think it fits the general case, one thing is that it might make sense to emphasize you are wrapping two separate objects, with _wrapFunc, one with the function call and one on return.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `bar` to call the wrapped `foo`, you have to *replace* `foo` in your `alpha` module by assigning the wrapped function: `alpha.foo = _wrapper(alpha.foo)` (or updating `alpha.__dict__` as you do in `_wrapFunc`).

In Python, code *is* data and program "symbols" are not different from normal variables. Whenever the code in `bar` is about to call `foo`, the Python interpreter will lookup the definition of `foo`, whatever it is at *that* moment.

Note that doing things like these will change your program at runtime, making it behave in a way that is not obvious from the source code. The technique is called [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) (the WP article has advice on how this can lead to problems if done carelessly).

Answer (score 0):

From my testing the first example gets the correct behaviour, where as the second one does not. I think in the later case `import *` will grab an unpatched version of `foo`, updating `alpha.foo` will wrap the function version of `foo` that `bar` calls but won't affect the `foo` in the local namespace.

Correct:

```
import alpha

def _wrapper(func): 
    def call(*args, **kwargs):
        print('entering')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('exiting') 
        return result
    return call

alpha.__dict__['foo'] = _wrapper(alpha.foo)
from alpha import *
```

Output (both functions call the patched `foo`):

```
entering
exiting
foo
entering
exiting
('foo', 'bar')
```

Incorrect:

```
import alpha
from alpha import *

def _wrapper(func): 
    def call(*args, **kwargs):
        print('entering')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('exiting') 
        return result
    return call

alpha.__dict__['foo'] = _wrapper(alpha.foo)
```

Output (only `bar` calls the patched `foo`, `foo` does not):

```
foo
entering
exiting
('foo', 'bar')
```